# Notification is disappearing automatically after some time (after calling stopforeground(false))

Tags: android, android-notifications

I started a foreground service and after the work is complete, i called `stopforeground(false)`

So that the user can clear it by swiping or by clearing all notifications. Everything seems to be ok and working as expected, i can clear it when it is done.

But the problem is, if i don't clear it explicitly, it is getting removed automatically. I don't want that. I want the notification to exist until the user clears it explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: once your service will stop GC will clear any created inactive instance and so your notification will wipe out.

Comment: Then how some of the notifications remain alive even after a long time? For example messanger notification or message notification

Comment: the service might be running indefinitely.

Comment: As far as i know, you can not clear a notification without calling stopforeground (false). Those notifications are clearable. I think you know what i mean. And sorry for the repetitive question. I am kind of new to all of this. And there are chances that i don't know what i am talking about.